# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2014' Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

Here is my code:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')

for i in range(len(linkElems)):
    t = linkElems[i].findAll(text=True)
    print(t)
```

This gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\Python\code.py", line 17, in <module>
     print(t)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2014' in position 9: character maps to <undefined>
```

The line `print(t)` is giving me the error.

I am using Python 3 and Beautiful Soup 4. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Btw, you can probably use `.get_text()` here: `[elm.get_text() for elm in soup.select('.r a')]`.

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback) in question. It shows which line makes problem.

Comment: you could add link to source data.

Comment: BTW: instead of `range(len())` we use ie. `for element in linkElems:`

Comment: @furas I have modified the code a bit, the line where I print the text is giving me error.

Comment: I would say: read again previous commend - always **FULL** error message - but never mind.

Comment: @furas I misunderstood your comment. I will edit the question now. :)

Comment: you have text in `unicode` but `print()` always have to convert it to encoding used by console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell - if terminal doesn't inform python what encodig it use then print() have problem to encode text. You can manually encode text ie. `print(t.encode('utf-8') but it may depend on system which you use - Linux mostly need `utf-8` but Windows may need `win1250` or other.

Comment: thank you for full error message - now we can see that you use Windows which tries to convert unicode  `'\u2014'` to `cp437` (Code Page 437) which is mostly used in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: `print()` tries to convert text into `cp437` to correctly display it in console but text has char with code `'\u2014'` which can't be converted - I don't use Window but I saw some command which change in cmd.exe `Code Page` into 'utf-8` - something like `cp6xxx` but I don't remeber what exactly - and this should resolve all problems with encodings.

Comment: Thanks @furas I got rid of the error. Using `encode('utf-8')` converts the character to `\xe2\x80\x94`. When I use `print(res.txt)`. This same character is printed as `&#8212;`.

Comment: BTW: [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file, you are using the encoding CP437, which on your operating system (which you haven't specified), is the default.

When the CP437 is examining the file, it encounters a character which it cannot encode (the 2014th Unicode character, either in hexadecimal or decimal, you haven't specified).

Therefore, it errors, telling you that it cannot encode the character.

The way to fix this is by changing the encoding to UTF-8, because it can decode all Unicode characters, and is probably what the file is really encoded in, because UTF-8 is being used worldwide.

To change it to UTF-8, use this code:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser", from_encoding="utf-8")
```

This changes the encoding to UTF-8 (because I added `from_encoding="utf-8"`), so now instead of executing `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\encodings\cp437.py` for encoding, it executes `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\encodings\utf8.py`, which encodes correctly.